# Exit List of Python Os.System Commands

Tags: python, terminal, sys

Let's say I run the following program from the terminal, and then immediately decide to stop it, I will have to hit control-c 5 times.  How do I make it so one control-c will exit the entire program?

```
os.system("python run_me1.py -lines -s {0} -u {1}".format(args.start, args.until))
os.system("python run_me2.py -derivs -tt")
if args.mike: os.system("python run_me3.py -f derivs.csv tt.csv")
os.system("gnumeric derivs.csv")
os.system("gnumeric tt.csv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a keyboard interrupt exception and replace os.system with subprocess.call.

Please not that for convenience of path resolution, I put the shell=True argument in, but that has security implications you should invalidate before doing this.

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.call("python run_me1.py -lines -s {0} -u {1}".format(args.start, args.until), shell=True)
    subprocess.call("python run_me2.py -derivs -tt", shell=True)
    if args.mike: subprocess.call("python run_me3.py -f derivs.csv tt.csv", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("gnumeric derivs.csv", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("gnumeric tt.csv", shell=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("exiting early")
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention you will need to change os.system to subprocess.call. I will update the answer. In general, what I originally wrote will work, but os.system is a special case.

Comment: @Jordan For the convenience of path resolution? If I do `subprocess.call(['python', 'run_me.py', '-lines', '-s', str(args.start), 'u', str(args.until)])` the path is resolved correctly as well.

Comment: Thanks glglgl. I took the lazy way. Your way is probably valid too. Thanks for the additional info.